# jQuery image rotate to replicate an animated gif

Tags: jquery

I need to recreate an animated gif that i own, in jQuery that would sequence through the images and repeat continuously.

so i have these images

```
<img src="1.png" />
<img src="2.png" />
<img src="3.png" />
<img src="4.png" />
```

There is no action required it should load on page start.

How is this achieved ?

note: i plan to use this on mobile devices, hence why i am not just calling the gif directly.

Thanks in advance ! :)

Comment: If you own the animated gif why not just include that in the src?  `<img src="animated.gif" />`

Comment: @JK because Animated gif's do not work on Android devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Spritely](http://www.spritely.net/documentation/) should do the trick. For example, put the four images, one after another in the same image, centered on their own 100px wide section, making the single image 400px wide, then:

**CSS**

```css
#sprite { width:100px; height:100px; background:#fff url('sprite.png') 0 0; }
```

**JS**

```js
$('#sprite').sprite({fps: 12, no_of_frames: 4});
```

Comment: you are a life saver, you didn't need to explain it further that link was plenty (just seen your update on refresh).  Thanks Man i can also confirm this works in iphone / android (need to test w7 phone) :)