# How to rotate an image?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to know how to rotate an image arround its center.

I want when i click on the image,the picture will start rotating as long as an ajax call not successful.

Please help me to find out.

Comment: Perhaps use a GIF animation? Easier.

Comment: use the image to do...

Comment: Mount your screen on a small electric motor and have it rotate ?

Comment: please refer to [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750358/with-jquery-how-can-i-implement-a-page-loading-animation]

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=rotate+image+css&rlz=1C1CHFX_frFR561FR561&oq=rotate+image+css&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2290j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Comment: http://loadergenerator.com/ OR http://preloaders.net/en/search/ajax+loader

Comment: Well he wants to switch a rotating image to a non-rotating image when an ajax call is successful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery image rotate to replicate an animated gif](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016032/jquery-image-rotate-to-replicate-an-animated-gif)

Answer (score 2):

Try any of this code on your css,(this will work only on mouse hover.)

```
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(5deg*);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(5deg);
  transform: scale(1.1) rotate(5deg);
```

- you can edit here to rotate on your desire.

Example,
CSS

```
.alt-col:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(5deg);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(5deg);
  transform: scale(1.1) rotate(5deg);
}
```

HTML

```
 <img src="" alt="" class="alt-col">
```

Answer (score -1):

You can switch images with css classes corresponding to the success of the ajax request :

- when the ajax request isn't over / fail -> use a gif or a CSS animation to rotate it
- when the request is complete, add a class "success" on your element to stop the animation, or change the image.

Comment: Yes but how. You've stated what he could do but not how to do it.

Comment: I gave him a way to do it. SO is not just about giving code to people. I'd rather explain a guy how to do it instead of giving him a working code that he doesn't understand.

Comment: BTW, as he didn't post any code part, I don't know how I could post code.

Comment: No SO, is not just about giving code, it's about giving code **and** explaining [why they should do it this way](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/203848/217110).